# Accessibility Preference Mode

Tags: html, user-interface, accessibility

I'm validating a desktop application developed by using `Java,C,C#` which are having two versions of the application.

1. Application that supports Accessibility features(Tabbing,Screen Reader)
2. Application that don't support Accessibility features(Tabbing,Screen
   Reader)

**Question:** Is it good to have the control for Accessibility preferences in admin level?

Note:These features can be controlled by Admin depends on the user login and if normal user wants to access the application by keyboard,user should request the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not good at all.

In general, there should be only one version of the app, and that version should be accessible to everyone. There are many advantages of such approach:

- Developers care about only one version of the same app, not two. This is actually a very large point because otherwise your "accessible" version will always come behind and lack all the newest features the "normal" version will have;
- Every user can get keyboard and screen reader accessibility free of charge, even if he/she doesn't need it all the time;
- There is no discrimination by health conditions;
- And more.

But if that is your decision to keep two versions, let it be so. What is really not good at all, is some admin control and any need to request an accessible version. "Sorry dear mr. Admin sir, I'm blind, wouldn't you mind please to kindly set my profile to use the accessible version?" What? I mean, WAT?
The user must have a control (a check box, a link, a button, whatever) that would allow him/her to switch from one version to another *back and forth*. I'm italicizing the "back and forth" thing because, again, if you have two versions, the chance is very high (really close to 100%, actually) that the "accessible" version would lack some features of the "normal" version, and an assistive technology user would need to switch back and forth to resolve some of his/her problems, sometimes coping with the "normal" version and spending most of his/her time in the "accessible" version.
But really, reconsider merging your two versions in one application, accessible to everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Actually I am not the developer for this application, I am validating the application from A11Y perspective.
Can you suggest me the standards on maintaining preference mode if required?

Comment: There's no other answer. Two versions means twice as much maintenance.
So, always launch the accessible version, and forget about a stupid preference and the unaccessible version.

Comment: There are no standards for that. Basically, Quentin is right, but if you still want to maintain two versions, make them add a check box ("Accessible Version" or "Screen Reader Mode") on the login form _and_ in the settings for the app. Again, users need to switch back and forth between versions, this is crucial.